# Why program is not working for n=100000 even if time complexity of sieve of eratothenes is O(nlog(log(n)))

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, sieve-of-eratosthenes

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"enter the no till which prime nos to be found :"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> prime(n+1,0);// we want n index too
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        if(prime[i]==0) {
            for(int j=i*i;j<=n;j=j+i) {
                prime[j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"prime numbers are: "<<endl;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        if(prime[i]==0) {
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

above code should be working for n>=100000 since n(log(log(n))) will equal to 400000.

Comment: Please don't add filler text to bypass the quality filters. Instead, describe exactly what the problem is: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Explain "not working" in more technical terms.

Comment: Do you know how to figure out what values of `i` will cause `int j = i * i` to overflow?  Do you know what value `j` will have when `i * i` overflows?

Answer (score 3):

Your `i*i` overflows a 32-bit `int` when `n` is more than about 46000.  This causes undefined behavior.  On my system, it wraps around and initializes `j` with a negative value, causing a segmentation fault when `prime[j]` is accessed.

This has nothing to do with time complexity.